# how to store and retrieve nonce in practice

Tags: storage, nonce

As nonce is supposed to be random and used only one time, when receiving a nonce, I need to check it with all past nonce records. That means I need a database to store every nonce I had before. Of course I can reduce the database size by limiting the life circle for nonces. But I am curious about how people handle this issue in practice. Is there any efficient way to store and verify a nonce?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `As nonce is supposed to be random` is not, strictly speaking, true. Nonce in general is only required to be unique.

It is, however, often convenient to generate nonce as (pseudo-)random bytes. In this case and if the nonce is sufficiently big (say, 12+ bytes) there is no need to check against previous nonces as you will never encounter a repeat in your life.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But I think nonce is used for preventing reply attack so that we do need to check the nonce if it appeared before.

Comment: If standard csprng of your system happens to produce same 12-byte chunks you have a bigger problem then repeating nonce.

Comment: The mathematical demonstration that "there is no need to check against previous nonces as you will never encounter a repeat in your life" is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50088697/1243247).

Answer (score 2):

You can store nonces in any way you want, e.g. in a database; also note that you don't need to store past nonces longer than their validity time. 
In fact, a nonce should be timestamped, and valid only during a limited time since its creation. For this, all systems (nonce producer, client, and server) need to be time synchronized.

Comment: Thanks. But I have another question about this: time synchronization. For example, nonce is used to prevent against reply attack, and timestamps may also have this benefit. Then why do we use nonce? I thought it was because the pricy time synchronization.

Comment: You do not need databases to store nonces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50088697/1243247 That is a non-cense :)